# How to get the href of a hyperlink, that comes after a specific word?

Tags: regex, extract, href

So, I have a string taken from the body of an email, which contains a hyperlink. Within that hyperlink is an href link which I am attempting to extract. The following line is the string in question:

```
View Documents: <a>MonthlyQuarterlyReport</a>
```

(I dont know how to create hyperlinks in this thread, so pretend MonthlyQuarterlyReport is the desired hyperlink that contains an href link).

My goal is to extract the href link within the above hyperlink. I assume the ideal approach to do this is by reading the portion of the string that says "Documents: " and then reading the first href that you find after that. As a side note, the text of the hyperlink itself is not a static element, it will change often and it wont be called "MonthlyQuarterlyReport" each time. So I guess my question here is, how do I extract the first href link that appears after the element, "Documents: " in this particular case?

This is what I have so far:

```
(?<=href\=").*.com(?="\>)
```

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to capture link connected with the text.

Assuming that you are using JavaScript and have html source of email.
Say suppose you have,

```
body = 'Documents: This is a <a class="someCSSClass" href="http://this-is-link">MonthlyQuarterlyReport</a> of 2020<a class="someCSSClass" href="htpps://new-link">New Link</a>'
```

So to extract href

```
arrMatch = body.match(/<a\s+class="someCSSClass"\s+href="([^"]*?)">/)
```

`arrMatch` will be

```
[
   0: 'Documents: This is a <a class="someCSSClass" href="http://this-is-link">'
   1: 'http://this-is-link'
]
```

and `arrMatch[1]` will have your link